# can't connect samsung printer to lubuntu

Tags: printing, samsung

my printer won't print.  I have LUBUNTU 14.1 (I think).  My printer is a Samsung scx-4623f.
sometimes the printer will start for a few seconds then quit...so i assume i don't have the correct driver.  I'm a newbie so if that is the problem I don't know how to download it.
help please.

Answer (score 1):

To install the driver, go to http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/SCX-4623F/XAA scroll down and click the download on the right. Assuming you have downloaded the file to your downloads folder, run the following commands to install the driver:

```
tar xvf ~/Downloads/uld_v1.00.06.tar.gz
cd uld
sudo ./install.sh
```

Then restart cups, avahi, and network-manager:

```
sudo service avahi-daemon restart
sudo service cups restart
sudo service cups-browsed restart
sudo service network-manager restart
```

If you get an error on cups-browsed don't worry about it.

Finally, unplug and plug back in the printer and if all else fails, reboot to make sure the changes take effect.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can install the correct driver at the following site: http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/SCX-4623F/XAA.  When there, scroll down the page until you come to Manuals and Downloads; click the link to download the driver.  Also, check your connections--from computer to printer, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If the printer still does not work properly after installing the drivers, I have had good luck by manually registering my printer with CUPS (CUPS is the printing system used for Unix-like operating systems).  This is not difficult to do either.  Go to http://localhost:631/. This is the CUPS 1.7.2 site where you will manually register your printer. When you get to the site, click on the Printers tab; you may very well see your printer listed here, but it may not have been registered automatically. Weather you see it listed or not, click on the Administration tab and enter your printer information. After you finish entering your printer information, your printer may very well start working properly. Make sure you are booted to Ubuntu and not Windows--if you are, in fact, double booting from the same computer.  Note: My printer was listed when I clicked on the Printer tab in CUPS, and it was also recognized by Ubuntu, but it still would not print because it was not registered automatically by CUPS.